# ASP.NET programming combining Response.Write with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET. Now I am in the process of modifying some elements in our site. My page has n images displayed. On clicking each images another set of images will be written on the page which is based on the image clicked. So the following code is used.

```
for i=1 to n
response.write"<img src="&SourceFile&" id="&i&" onClick=func(this)>"
next
```

And my function code is as follows

```
newSrc="myweb.com/Images/img1.gif"
function func(x)
{
     switch(parseInt(x.id))
     {
          case 1:x.src=newSrc;
                 break;
      }
 }
```

when i checked i found the error x is null or not an object. Can you please help me spot the errors...

Comment: The provided code should never result in that error as `this` from an HTML event will *never* evaluate to null; perhaps `func` assigned as the handler elsewhere or there is different code that uses `x`?

Comment: Is this Classic ASP, or ASP.NET?

Comment: Actually the issue/question here is on javascript part. Nothing to do with asp/asp.net. What browser do you use ? how the html part is rendering ? I can not spot any issue as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Ja4Cj/

Comment: Why are you coding like this? You're coding ASP.NET as though it were "Classic" ASP!

Answer (score 0):

you need to to this.id

```
response.write"<img src="&SourceFile&" id='"&i&"' onClick='func(this.id)'>"
```

make sure that your function is `<script></script>` client side